# HTML form triggers php code in file, how do i get back to html?

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I am collecting data in a form which calls on a php file to put the data into mysql.  It works fine, but after the data gets into the database, the browser just shows a blank page and in the browser input bar is the line

http://nameofmyste.net/mfb1.php

It is as though the HTML sent me to the php code where runs fine on the server then it just gets stuck, and stays there.  How do I "get back" to my html script?

The call form action command looks like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  action="mfb1.php" method="post" >
```

The php code exists in the file mfb1.php and works fine and just terminates with the standard closing "?> " at the end.

Thanks for your help.

Sorry for the delay in getting back to the question, and very sorry for my incorrect use of the forum, I am new and learning...

I have done some work since the original question and have created a very simple AJAX example that should work fine, but it doesn't.  Here is the HTML file with the js function localform.  It uses a synchronous AJAX call (3rd parameter set to "false") to invoke my php code, which is below as well.

It runs fine, I see the phrase "we made it" which replaces the "replace here" text on the html page, just like it is supposed to.  But, within half a second, the "we made it" goes away and the "replace here" text shows up again.

It is as though the html code were running again form the top.  The address in the browser bar, after the submit now reads

```
http://bruwptest.netne.net/Test%20Files/ajaxtester.html?
```

The question mark at the end is new.

Here is the code:

ajaxtester.php:

```
<?php
echo "we made it";
?>
```

ajaxtester.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
 <h1>AJAX Tester</h1>

 <p>Echo here from the server: <span id="text">replace here</span></p> 

<form  onclick="localform()"> 
<button type="submit"  >Submit</button>       
</form>

<script>
    function localform() {       
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "ajaxtester.php",false);
        xhttp.send();
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

My question is why the html page is refreshing and overwriting the "we made it" that I just wrote there from the php?

Comment: you tagged as php, so where is it? Plus you seem to be using bootstrap here. That's boostrap syntax. or JS/Ajax/jQuery.

Comment: Either you're not returning any data, or your getting an error 500 after the database insert runs. Check your server logs.

Comment: Please add your PHP script too.

Comment: There are also HTML code in your 'mfb1.php' script?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to you php file to display errors, but also please edit your question to show the php code

Comment: In **mfb1.php**, after successfully inserting value to database give `header("location:somepage.html");`

Comment: Thank you all, I used the following to get back from the php code:

    echo "<script>window.location = 'http://bruwptest.netne.net/indexwc.html#enter'</script>";

that was the page where I "called" the php from.

Answer (score 2):

> It is as though the HTML sent me to the php code

Well, yes.  That's what you specified:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  action="mfb1.php" method="post" >
                               <!-- right here ----^ -->
```

> then it just gets stuck

Well, what does `mfb1.php` *do*?  What *output* does it generate?  If it doesn't render any HTML to the browser, then no HTML is rendered to the browser.

Or if there's an error and error reporting isn't turned on, there may be no valid output to render to the browser.  Turn on error reporting during debugging, check your logs, etc.

You can, within that script, output any HTML that you like.  Anything outside of `<?php ?>` tags is just sent directly to the client, so put any HTML that you want there.

Alternatively, at the logical completion of the script you could also redirect the user to another page:

```
header('Location: somePage.html');
```

This would return a response to the user's browser indicating that it should make a new request for `somePage.html`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send to client a redirect `location` to your original HTML page; at the end of your php script, write:

```
header( "Location: YourHtmlFileUrlHere" );
exit;
```

The `exit` command is not mandatory, if the command is at the end of script.

**Please note:** The `header` command fails if before in page there are **ANY OUTPUT**